# C++ Reference Reassignment

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am seeing undefined behaviour in below code. I can't quite pin-point the exact issue, it'd be much help if someone could take a look and assist. Below is built using gcc 6.3.1.

```
DBConn* dbconn = new DBConn();
DBConn& d = *dbconn; //reference
....
delete dbconn;
dbconn = new DBConn();
d = *dbconn;
```

Assignment (=) operator of DBConn

```
DBConn& DBConn::operator =(const DBConn &rhs) {
   if(this != &rhs) {
    // deletes member variable pointers initialised with objects created using new operator
    // deep copies some member variables
   }
   return *this;
}
```

1. The app sometimes crashes when the second `d = *dbconn` is executed.
2. Does `d = *dbconn` reassign the reference variable?

From what I could gather, the app would go into undefined behaviour when memory address of `d` is not same as `dbconn`; executing the code in assignment operator's overloaded method because `this != &rhs`.

Comment: References cannot be reassigned, ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference `d` is *dangling* once `dbconn` is deleted.

Yes, the behaviour on accessing `d` after that is *undefined*. (Note that the pointer value `dbconn` is *indeterminate* after the `delete`.)

References cannot be rebound, so the subsequent

```
d = *dbconn;
```

yields a diagnostic.

Comment: Is it safe to say that this code is not designed properly? I assume that the original author intended to reuse `d` with the "updated" reference to the new db connection. Is there any way to reuse `d`?

Comment: @user2780757: No. `DBConn& d` is basically a dangling pointer. Using it in any way whatsoever is undefined and likely to crash.